# Change input reference to 1 - 5 V

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am using a sensor which delivers a 4 to 20 mA output.
Converting this with a 250 Ohm resistor to ground I convert this to a 1 - 5 V output.

My question how can I change the 0V reference, so I can use the full spectrum
I found a way to change the 5V reference (analogReference()).
Is it possible to change the 0V reference of a input to 1V?

Any other solution to my problem is welcome as well! (As long as it doesn't involve I2C or anything which lowers my looptime drastically)

Comment: Not possible with the Uno, as it has only GND-referenced single-ended inputs.

Comment: On which board is this possible? Is there another way to use the full resolution?

Comment: Don't know for sure. The Mega is based on the ATmega2560 chip, which has differential inputs to its ADC. **If** those are available on the board connectors, and if you can provide your 1 V reference to the negative input, it should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ADC is ground-referenced, and there's no way to change that. The question is if that's necessary. The ADC has a 10-bit resolution, that's good for 1024 different levels between 0 and 5 V. If you convert the 4-20mA with a 250 Ω resistor to a 1-5 V range you still can discriminate between more than 800 different values.

If that's not enough you can use a differential amplifier to subtract 1 V:

[image]

By choosing R3 = 1.25 R1 you convert the 0-4 V range to a 0-5 V range.

Comment: I like the differntial amplifier answer. But, what are V1 and V2? Why are you talking about 0-4 to 0-5 when I have a 1-5? Thanks in advance!

Comment: 0-4v is 1-5v with 1v subtracted as the answer says.  V2 is your signal at 1-5v, v1 is 1v reference voltage.  V1 is subtracted from V2 (so 1-5 becomes 0-4) and then amplified by R3/R1 to make 0-4 into 0-5.

Comment: Use a 2nd opamp section to make a unity gain buffer (OA out to OA-) use this to buffer a pot that you adjust to 1V (Pot feed OA+,OA out to V1. ) || Make One of the R3's adjustable using a bigger value pot than R3 fixed. eg if R3 = 10K make pot say 15K so you can adjust it either side of 10k slightly. This is used to make gain of V1 & V2 inputs track. || Overall accuracy is limited by balance of resistors so use 1% or better still 0.1%. (may not need pot above if R's are matched well enough).   IF you want to avoid having to supply matched R's buy an "instrumentation amplifier" IC.